# Magento Cart Sales Rule, website_ids does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, cart

I'm building an Ajax Cart system, as part of my own theme. When I try adding a product, simple or configurable, I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'website_ids' in 'where clause'
```

Here's my code:

```
        function add_to_cartAction($product = false)
        {
            $data = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['data']) , true);
        if(!$product)
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($data['entity_id']);
        }
        try{
            if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple'){

                $params = array(
                    'qty' => $data['quantity'] , 
                    'product' => $product->getId()
                );
                $this->addProduct($product , $params);

                die(base64_encode(json_encode(array('success' => 'Successfully added product to cart'))));

            }else{
                $options = $data['attrs'];

                $_matchedItem = null;

                $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

                foreach($childProducts as $item)
                {
                    $matchAmount = count($options);
                    $matched = 0;
                    foreach($options as $attr => $option)
                    {
                        if($item->getData($attr) == $option)
                        {
                            $matched++;
                        }
                    }
                    if($matched == $matchAmount)
                    {
                        $_matchedItem = $item;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($_matchedItem == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Matched Item is null");
                }
                $params = array(
                    'qty' => $data['quantity'] , 
                    'product' => $_matchedItem->getId()
                );

                $this->addProduct($_matchedItem , $params);

                die(base64_encode(json_encode(array('success' => 'Successfully added product to cart'))));

            }
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    function addProduct($product , $params)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $cart->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $cart->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        $cart->getQuote()->addProduct($product , $params['qty']);

        $cart->getQuote()->save();
        $cart->save();
    }
```

Whenever I try adding a product to the cart, I get a problem with the `salesrule` table, saying the column website_ids doesn't exist, Although on a working version of Magento, It doesn't exist, yet works. It's really baffling me, Anyone have a solution for this?

EDIT*
Added Screenshot of salesrule table.

[image: phpmyadmin screenshot]